# too slow TTFB(latency) with go language in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

[image: Check this ttfb]

I'm testing go lang in appengine. But it's too slow response. I've checked with chrome and found that the problem is 'Waiting(TTFB)'

The source code is very simple and official example(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-try-go).

What's wrong? Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local test performance has nothing to do with production performance. There is nothing wrong with what you see.

Usually first requests are slower than subsequent ones as the AppEngine SDK performs file system scans, compiling and first-time loading and execution of package `init()` functions of your application's code.

What you see is a 1-second `Waiting (TTFB)` time, it stands for Time To First Byte ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing)):

> Time spent waiting for the initial response, also known as the Time To First Byte. This time captures the latency of a round trip to the server in addition to the time spent waiting for the server to deliver the response.

This 1 second TTFB most likely includes all the tasks I listed above the SDK has to perform, which isn't so bad if you think about that.

Don't worry, production environment runs "pre-compiled" native binary code, none of these have to be performed and you will see most likely a response time (TTFB) around 20-30 ms.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. And I've had slow latency with production performance because of my region. I'm in Korea. I've tried the appengine with go in US central via cloud computing. That response with 37ms.